# How to solve differential equation $f(y^2)\sqrt{y^2+y'^2}-\frac{f(y^2)y'^2}{\sqrt{y^2+y'^2}}=C$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation I need to solve:

$$f(y^2)\sqrt{y^2+y'^2}-\displaystyle\frac{f(y^2)y'^2}{\sqrt{y^2+y'^2}}=C,$$

where $y=y(x), \;y'=y'(x)=\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}, f(y^2)$ is some function of $y^2$and $C$ is some constant. I'm stuck with this and don't know what to do. I tried the following:

$$f(y^2)\sqrt{y^2+y'^2}-\displaystyle\frac{f(y^2)y'^2}{\sqrt{y^2+y'^2}}=C $$
$$\frac{f(y^2)\left(y^2+y'^2\right)-f(y^2)y'^2}{\sqrt{y^2+y'^2}}=C$$
$$\frac{f(y^2)y^2}{\sqrt{y^2+y'^2}}=C$$
$$\frac{f(y^2)^2y^4}{y^2+y'^2}=D$$
$$y'^2=\frac{f(y^2)^2y^4-Dy^2}{D}$$
$$y'=\pm \sqrt{\frac{f(y^2)^2y^4-Dy^2}{D}}$$
$$y'=\pm E\sqrt{f(y^2)^2y^4-Dy^2}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm E\sqrt{f(y^2)^2y^4-Dy^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{f(y^2)^2y^4-Dy^2}}\;dy=\pm E\;dx$$

Any hints? Thank you :)

P.S.

This problem is part of my earlier problem which I asked here:

[How to transform $ \int_a^b f(x^2+y(x)^2)\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}\;dx$ into polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1105063/53500)

The whole problem can be seen on that post. The idea was to convert the problem into polar coordinates and then solve optimal function $y$ in the functional. I used the Euler-Lagrange equation where the functional does not contain independent variable, that is the equation:

$$F(y,y')-y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=C,$$

where in my problem $F(y,y')=f(y^2)\sqrt{y^2+y'^2}$

[Here](http://users.utu.fi/yurnik/cv.pub_files/Supplements.pdf#page=45) is link to my reference of the Euler-Lagrange equation

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @AlexR aah, sorry about that :) Understood and will do this in future :) Thank you

Comment: It seems hard to continue without knowing $f$.

Comment: Hi @mickep yes :/ This is part of a problem given to me in my Calculus of Variations course. The funtion $f$ is not specified in the problem..

Comment: Is this your original question, or have you arrived at it during your solution? If this is not your original question, can you show the original one?

Comment: Hi @mickep no it is not. I updated my post =) This is part of a bigger problem :) The whole problem can be seen in the link I provided above

Comment: @mickep Do you think there is a possibility that I have misinterpreted the problem. At the end of my problem it is stated that "Solve it to optimality". I interpreted that I'm supposed to solve the functional for optimal function after I have changed the representation into polar coordinates?

Comment: There is a risk of misunderstanding. I suggest you to go and discuss these questions with your teacher. I don't know how to proceed with the information you have given here...

Comment: Hi @mickep thank you for your help =) I will do that.